# Flexible algorithm to calculate possibilities of all possible scenarios

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I've been struggling for a little while to find or figure out algorithm.

The task:
Basically, I have an array of probabilities:

```
var input = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1];
```

Let's name these inputs accordingly to: A, B, C and D.

And I also have a variable "m", which can tell me how many of these things needs to happen in order to get the result.
For example:

```
var m = 2;
```

This variable m is telling me that the event will happen if any of those two (or more) probabilities will happen.

So in this case, for event to happen, all possible ways for event to happen is:

ABCD
ABC
ABD
BCD
AB
AC
AD
BC
BD and CD

Now I need to calculate their probabilities, which I already have algorithms to calculate AND and OR (where input is just a probabilities array).

AND:

```
if (input.length > 0) {
    output = 1;
}
for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    output = input[i] * output;
}
```

OR:

```
if (input.length > 0) {
    output = input[0];
}
for (i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
    output = (output + input[i]) - (output * input[i]);
}
```

So I am struggling on figuring out how to loop through all possible possibilities... And to have something like:
(A and B and C and D) or (A and B and C) or (A and B and D)... and so on... I hope you get the idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "probabilities will happen" ?

Comment: Every probability input indicates a chance of an event to happen. For example: 0.5 probability that the coin flip will be on tails, 0.1 probability that card drawn will be ace and 0.2 probability that card human will select color red. Now I need to calculate what are the odds of happening of at least 2 events.

Comment: So in this case, it is 0.5*0.1 or 0.5*0.2 or 0.1*0.5 or 0.5*0.1*0.2.

Comment: Are you actually interested in all the possibilies or just the result of (A and B and C and D) or (A and B and C) or (A and B and D)... ?

Comment: Does the input sum up to 1 or not?

Comment: @juvian just the result

Comment: @JonasWilms not neccessarily

Comment: Are we able to assume that the list of probabilities is independent? That seems like a non-trivial assumption to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the combinations of your desired array with a minimum of two by using a recursive function which generates all the possible combinations.

```js
function getC(array, min) {
    function iter(i, temp) {
        var t = temp.concat(array[i]);
        if (i === array.length) return;
        iter(i + 1, t);
        iter(i + 1, temp);
        if (t.length >= min) {
            result.push(t);
        }
    }
    
    var result = [];
    iter(0, []);
    return result;
}

var input = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1];
console.log(getC(input, 2).map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple non-recursive solution to enumerate all combinations with at least `m` elements.

```js
range = n => [...Array.from({length: n}).keys()]

mask = xs => b => xs.filter((_, n) => b & (1 << n))

at_least = n => xs => xs.length >= n

//

a = [...'ABCD']
m = 2

result = range(1 << a.length).map(mask(a)).filter(at_least(m))

console.log(result.map(x => x.join('')))
```

Since JS bit arithmetics is limited to 32 bits, this only works for m < 32.

Comment: @JonasWilms: sure, added a note about that

Answer (score 1):

You could go over all combimations of 2 elements (`AB`, `CD` etc.) with two nested loops:

```
 for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  for(let j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++) {
    // possible combination: i and j
    for(let k = j; k < input.length; k++) {  
     // possible combination: i, j, k
     // and so on
    }
  }
}
```

for at least `m` elements that can be generalized with a nested generator that generates an array of indices (`[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [0, 1, 2]`):

```
 function* combinations(length, m = 1, start = 0) {
   // Base Case: If there is only one index left, yield that:
   if(start === length - 1) {
     yield [length - 1];
    return;
   }

   // Otherwise go over all left indices
   for(let i = start; i < length; i++) {
     // And get all further combinations, for 0 that will be [1, 2], [1] and [2]
     for(const nested of combinations(length, m - 1, i + 1)) {
      // Yield the nested path, e.g. [0, 1], [0, 1, 2] and [0, 2]
      yield [i, ...nested];
     }
     // If the minimum length is already reached yield the index itself
     if(m <= 1) yield [i];
  }
}
```

Now for every combination, we just have to multiply the probabilities and add them up:

```
 let result = 0;

 for(const combination of combimations(input.length, m))
   result += combination.reduce((prev, i) => prev * input[i], 1);
```